# Can anyone find the error in this MySQL code? (beginner)

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE TABLE `students`.`studentinfo` (
id int,
name varchar,
age int
);
ENGINE = InnoDB
COMMENT = 'test';
```

I am using the MySQL Workbench and I am trying to create a table named students. However my code gives the error message

```
Operation failed: There was an error while applying the SQL script to the database.
Executing:
CREATE TABLE `students`.`studentinfo` (
id int,
name varchar,
age int
);
ENGINE = InnoDB
COMMENT = 'test';

ERROR 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ',
age int
)' at line 3
SQL Statement:
CREATE TABLE `students`.`studentinfo` (
id int,
name varchar,
age int
)
```

I tried to solve this by removing the table like so:

```
CREATE TABLE `students`.`studentinfo` (
)
ENGINE = InnoDB
COMMENT = 'test';
```

and even then it still doesn't work! It gives the same error message:

```
Operation failed: There was an error while applying the SQL script to the database.
Executing:
CREATE TABLE `students`.`studentinfo` (
)
ENGINE = InnoDB
COMMENT = 'test';



ERROR 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')
ENGINE = InnoDB
COMMENT = 'test'' at line 2
SQL Statement:
CREATE TABLE `students`.`studentinfo` (
)
ENGINE = InnoDB
COMMENT = 'test'
```

Comment: Did you check the [manual, how to define a CHAR/VARCHAR column](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/char.html)? Do you see any difference between the examples there and your example?

Comment: Don't save the age as it changes every year, save the birthday

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`varchar` needs a length:

```
CREATE TABLE `students`.`studentinfo` (
id int,
name varchar(100),
age int
)
```

Comment: hey if I didn't put a space between `studentinfo` and ( would that cause an error?

Comment: No the blank will be ignored

Comment: @uggupuggu SQL, unlike Python etc, does not care about indentation and whitespaces. you can basically write everything on one line with nearly no spaces. also, do not forget to accept this answer as solution if it made the trick!

Comment: What if i added a semicolon after the last ) after age int?

Comment: @uggupuggu try it out or read the manuals about sql syntax.